# Does smartgwt supports mulitple record updates on one HTTP call

Tags: java, spring, smartgwt

In smartgwt, if we want to update or add new record to listgrid, it allows to add one record at one HTTP call. I want to add or update multiple records at one HTTP call. I am using Springframework. I found some references to resolve this problem by queuing requests and send to queued requests to backend at one HTTP call. However, I didn't get clear understand on there explanation. I am wondering if someone can provide an example code to both client side and server side logic.

This is the reference link : 
https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/RestDataSource.html

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways that this can be done with SmartGWT. I think one of the simplest ways is by using the in-built sql datasources.

With the SQLDataSource, you can perform an add operation like this.

```
Record record = new Record();
record.setAttribute("name", "Tom")
record.setAttribute("age", "28");

Record record2 = new Record();
record2.setAttribute("name", "John")
record2.setAttribute("age", "50");

DataSource myDataSource = DataSource.get("myDataSource")
myDataSource.addData(record);
myDataSource.addData(record2);
```

But this would send two separate HTTP requests, one for each add operation. However you can put these into a single HTTP call by using the RPCManager. This can be done like this:

```
RPCManager.startQueue();
myDataSource.addData(record);
myDataSource.addData(record2);
RPCManager.sendQueue(new RPCQueueCallback() {
        @Override
        public void execute(RPCResponse... rpcResponses) {

        }
});
```

If you choose to use sql datasources 'out-of-the-box' like this, then you can save/update with very little server-side code. You just need to have a datasource that has been defined a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<DataSource
        ID="Person"
        serverType="sql"
        tableName="Person"
        >
    <fields>
        <field primaryKey="true" name="personId" autoGenerated="true" hidden="true"/>
        <field name="name" length="100" type="text" required="true"  />
        <field name="age" type="integer" required="true"  />

    </fields>
</DataSource>
```

However, if you want or need to have additional logic besides basic add/update operations (if you want to be able to put code on the server side - then you will need to define a server-side bean). You can define a server-side bean in your datasource in several ways. The way I do this is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<DataSource
        ID="Person"
        serverType="sql"
        tableName="Person"

        >
     <serverObject lookupStyle="spring" bean="personDataSource" />
    <fields>
        <field primaryKey="true" name="personId" autoGenerated="true" hidden="true"/>
        <field name="name" length="100" type="text" required="true"  />
        <field name="age" type="integer" required="true"  />

    </fields>
</DataSource>
```

And then you need to define a server-side bean a bit like this:

```
@Component("personDataSource")
public class PersonDataSource {

    @Autowired
    PersonService service;

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PersonDataSource.class);

    public DSResponse add(DSRequest dsRequest) {
        try {
            String primaryKey = (String) dsRequest.getFieldValue("personId");


            service.create(person);

            return new DSResponse().setSuccess();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to add " + dsRequest.getValues(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new DSResponse().setFailure();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Alan. I have used this method. My server side is model driven. How will be the server side code this.??